# sqldf gives different results in console and in code

Tags: r, sqldf

My problem is the following: when I run the same SQL query in the R Studio console and in a function, I get two different results, and I was hoping that someone could tell me where the side effect is coming from. The dataframe that's being used contains only 3 fields (id, timestamp, cluster).

My function is the following:

```
get_cluster_boundaries <- function(clustering_result) {
  library(sqldf)
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(clustering_result))
  all_clusters <- sqldf(paste("SELECT DISTINCT(cluster) FROM ", dfname, sep=""))
  for(cluster_no in all_clusters) {
    lquery <- paste("SELECT min(timestamp) FROM ", dfname, " WHERE cluster = ", cluster_no, sep="")
    lower_end <- sqldf(lquery)
    uquery <- paste("SELECT max(timestamp) FROM ", dfname, " WHERE cluster = ", cluster_no, sep="")
    upper_end <- sqldf(uquery)
    print(paste("Cluster ", cluster_no, " starts from ", lower_end, " to ", upper_end, sep=""))
  }
}
```

This gives me a single result for all the clusters, while copypasting the individual uquery and lquery and executing them in the R studio console by still using sqldf gives me the correct starting date and ending date of each cluster.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my guess, but I can't be sure it's working, is that all_clusters is a data.frame, not a vector. In sqldf help page we have

> The result of the specified select statement is output as a data
>   frame.

try with

```
for (cluster_no in all_clusters[,1])
```